# Не приходят сообщения на сервер

Tags: python, c#, сокет

Проблема заключается в том что после подключения по сокетам сервер не выводит сообщение которое прислал клиент, клиент сделан на Python, сервер на C#.
Код класса сервера:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


class ConnectionServer {
        Socket sock;
        Socket client;
        NetworkStream stream;

        public ConnectionServer(int port) {
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new(IPAddress.Any, port);
            sock = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sock.Bind(endPoint);
        }

        public void StartConnection(int connections) {
            sock.Listen(connections);
            client = sock.Accept();
            stream = new NetworkStream(client);
        }

        public void SendData(string myData) {
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myData);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        public string GetData(int bufferSize = 4096) {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            var bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
}
```

А вот код клиента:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 8080))
print("C#!")

client.send(bytes("avcd", encoding='utf-8'))
print("sended")
client.close()
```

Comment: В показанном вами коде сервера нет ничего связанного с выводом. Где и как вы пытаетесь что-нибудь выводить?

Comment: @andreymal Ой, простите.
`SocketServer serv = new SocketServer(8080);`
`serv.StartConnection(1);`
`Console.WriteLine(serv.GetData(1024));`